# C: Dynamically synthesizing aggregate data types at runtime

Tags: c, struct, memory-alignment

*DISCLAIMER: This question is about a general concept. I've "dumbed down" the question so that I can ask it here clearly - without needing to provide the entire context of it's actual application. I can already foresee a bunch of comments like "why would you ever do that?" But, if the question could just be taken at face value, I'd appreciate it!*

Suppose you wanted to dynamically synthesize some data structures in C at runtime out of some pre-defined structs.

The best way I know how to ask this question is through a code sample.

In the following, we've defined two structs: `Foo` and `Bar`. I also define a struct `FooBar` to illustrate at least one difference between the compile-time generated composite type and the runtime generated "dynamically synthesized" type.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Foo {
    char junk1;
    char junk2;
} Foo;

typedef struct Bar {
    int junk3;
    int junk4;
} Bar;

typedef struct FooBar {
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
} FooBar;

int main()
{
    printf("Sizes: %li, %li, %li\n", sizeof(Foo), sizeof(Bar), sizeof(FooBar));
    // Prints: Sizes: 2, 8, 12
    // Because Foo is aligned on 1-byte boundaries and has total size of 2 bytes.
    // Bar is aligned on 4-byte boundaries and has total size of 8 bytes.
    // But FooBar is aligned on 4-byte boundaries due to the ints in Foo. Therefore,
    // the compiler added 2-bytes of padding after the foo member.

    // The following "works", but only allocates 10 bytes, and
    // "Bar" members are now "misaligned":
    void * syntheticFooBar = malloc(sizeof(Foo) + sizeof(Bar));
    ((Foo*)syntheticFooBar)->junk1 = 1;
    ((Foo*)syntheticFooBar)->junk2 = 2;
    ((Bar*)(syntheticFooBar + sizeof(Foo)))->junk3 = 3;
    ((Bar*)(syntheticFooBar + sizeof(Foo)))->junk4 = 4;

    free(syntheticFooBar);
    return 0;
}
```

So my questions would be:

1.) How badly would the lack of proper data alignment affect performance? Given the overhead involved with accessing "members" of the synthetic structures, is data-alignment even a significant contributing factor?

2.) Is there a better way of doing this given the constraints of run-time synthesis?

Comment: you can always associate a type marker for structs that you want to do this with and embed them within each other. Let's say foo extends bar then there would be a struct bar inside a struct foo. And some use of the containerof macro can get you these extensions.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid adding padding?

Comment: @VaughnCato - No, I am not trying to avoid adding the padding - and if there were a way to calculate and add the padding on the fly somehow (and if that would be significant, performance-wise), I'd happily do so.

Comment: @JesusRamos - Unless I'm misunderstanding your comment (which I very well may be) - it sounds like your suggestion would require that I know the possible combinations of structs ahead of time - which I don't.

Comment: A pretty reliable way to find the alignment of a type `T` is to use `sizeof(struct {T a;char b})-sizeof(T)`.

Comment: @VaughnCato - I'm not sure how that helps me? I'd have to take the max value of that function for each data member in each struct to determine proper alignment, wouldn't I? I don't think C programs contain any sort of metadata about struct members that's accessible at runtime.

Comment: You have to make sure that each member has the proper alignment.  In your example, you would see that `Bar` has a 4-byte alignment (for example), so you would add two extra bytes between `Foo` and `Bar` in your synthesized struct.

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes, I specifically pointed out that fact in the example. That was the point. But I don't think I "have" to make sure they are aligned. I'll simply suffer a performance penalty if they aren't. Please see question #1 after the example.

Comment: The side-effects of using non-aligned objects is platform dependent.  On some platforms it may cause a crash.  Are you thinking that maintaining proper alignment will be too expensive?

Comment: That depends entirely on processor.  x86 will probably be okay (though I can't recall if that's true of `double`, which tends to be the most constrained type), but there are definitely processors where you'll get a memory bus fault if alignment isn't correct.  The main fact is this code has unspecified behavior under the C Standard. You'll never be sure that some future system change won't cause your code to core dump.  I'd run away from this idea hard and fast.

Comment: See http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/08/18/understanding-x86-vs-arm-memory-alignment-on-android this article that shows 8-byte data like double and long-long require 8-byte alignment, but other quantities have smaller requirements on ARM.  So on this processor it would be easy to create examples where your code will fail.

Comment: You could simply force all your structs to be 4-byte (or 8-byte) aligned by adding reserved members to the structs, but that's pretty wasteful if you shove lots of 2-byte structs in a row.  Perhaps you could create some metadata for each struct in the form of an alignment value and use a macro to obtain that from the structure's name.  *eg* `ALIGN(Bar)` would translate to a constant somewhere whose value is 4.

Comment: RISC chips (PowerPC, SPARC) object to misaligned data types by generating a SIGBUS signal and core dump; this tends to be bad for program performance.

Comment: @Gene Thanks for the insightful comments! Much appreciated!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the PowerPC/SPARC info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.) How badly would the lack of proper data alignment affect performance? Given the overhead involved with accessing "members" of
>   the synthetic structures, is data-alignment even a significant
>   contributing factor?

This is entirely dependent on the CPU architecture and compiler.  On some systems you may just have a performance penalty, but on others you could get a crash.

> 2.) Is there a better way of doing this given the constraints of run-time synthesis?

Here's an example of how you might create a properly aligned synthesized struct at runtime:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  char junk1;
  char junk2;
} A;

typedef struct {
  int junk3;
  int junk4;
} B;

typedef struct {
  double junk5;
  char junk6;
} C;

static size_t roundUp(size_t value,size_t factor)
{
  return value+factor-1-((value+factor-1)%factor);
}

#define alignof(type) (sizeof(struct {type a;char b;})-sizeof(type))

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  size_t offsets[3];
  size_t pos = 0;

  pos = roundUp(pos,alignof(A));
  offsets[0] = pos;
  pos += sizeof(A);

  pos = roundUp(pos,alignof(B));
  offsets[1] = pos;
  pos += sizeof(B);

  pos = roundUp(pos,alignof(C));
  offsets[2] = pos;
  pos += sizeof(C);

  {
    char *foobar = malloc(pos);
    A *a = (A *)(foobar + offsets[0]);
    B *b = (B *)(foobar + offsets[1]);
    C *c = (C *)(foobar + offsets[2]);
    a->junk1 = 1;
    a->junk2 = 2;
    b->junk3 = 3;
    b->junk4 = 4;
    c->junk5 = 5;
    c->junk6 = 6;
    free(foobar);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The alignment of a particular struct is determined by creating a struct with the original struct and an extra char.  The compiler will automatically add enough padding to make sure that the necessary alignment is preserved if you were to use an array of these structs, so by measuring the difference in sizes, we get the proper alignment.

Using the alignment information, we can create a table of where each member of the synthesized struct should live relative to the beginning.  We just have to make sure that the position of each member has the proper alignment by rounding the position up to the nearest multiple of the alignment.

You should be able to generalize this to any number of members.

Note that if you wanted to determine the overall size if your synthesized struct (what sizeof() might return), so that you could create an array of these synthesized structs, then you need to get the combined alignment requirement and roundUp the final pos to that factor.  The combined alignment will be the least common multiple of the individual alignments.

Comment: Nice. Would you mind adding to your answer the information in the comments to the question (that misaligned data will crash on some architectures) before I mark it as accepted?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an error in your calculation for the offsets? I'm getting much larger numbers than seem right.

Comment: Something doesn't seem right. If you reorder it: C, A, B, then your size and the compiler don't agree.

Comment: I think the answer may be flawed because the compiler uses the maximum padding of all elements.

Comment: @Steve: In principle, the least common multiple would be necessary.  For example, if you had two members and one of the members had an alignment of two, and the other had an alignment of three, then you would need an overall alignment of six.  However, in most cases, the alignments are going to be powers of two, in which case the least common multiple is the same as the maximum.

Comment: @Steve: In my example, I'm allocating memory based on the last unaligned position, which may be smaller than what `sizeof` would return for an equivalent compile-time defined struct.  This doesn't matter when allocating a single object, since the extra padding would never be accessed.